# How to add vertical and horizontal scrollbar to the Kendo chart

Tags: angular, angular6, kendo-grid, kendo-chart

I am using the kendo charts, I want the category in y-axis and date in x-axis to static and want scroll bar for chart instead of taking a div and also want the bar size small and the font size should be less than in the example.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsvks7?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it happen, had to

1. add a style section to your component definition
2. removed the inline style from the div

**app.component.ts** changes below:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div >
          <kendo-chart style="width: 3832px" [valueAxis]="valueAxis" [ngStyle]="{ 'height.px': chartHeight }">
            <kendo-chart-plot-area background="#F2F2F2"></kendo-chart-plot-area>
            <kendo-chart-series>
                <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let series of model"
                type="rangeBar" [spacing]="-1" [data]="series.data" [opacity]="0.8" fromField="Start" toField="End" categoryField="Category">
                </kendo-chart-series-item>
            </kendo-chart-series>         
          </kendo-chart>
        </div>
    `,
    styles:[` 
      kendo-chart{ max-width: 525px; max-height: 300px;}
      ::ng-deep g>text{ font-size: 11px !important;}
    `]
})
```

complete [working demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsvks7-ps16u2?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can i add vertical scrollbar to it by keeping the height of chart fixed.

Comment: i don't understand. the scroll bar will auto emerge if the height of the chart is greater than the browser

Comment: chart is one of the component in the page and does not occupy whole page so i need the chart height fixed with scrollbar.

Comment: the scrollbar is required on the page or the chart... like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsvks7-xepyp6?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: i need the scrollbar for chart and not for the page even if there is no other content the chart should have the scroll. Pages scrollbar is the default functionality of the browser.

Comment: oh, ok... check it now: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsvks7-xepyp6?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: really thank you for your quick help one more question can we have the dates outside the scroll bar (scrollbar should be applied only to the bars)

Comment: overflow and height properties not working on <path>... so unless there is a way to do it in the Kendo Charts documentation, not gonna happen through css